# How can I configure SSL for an IRC bot in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, irc

How can I fix this error :

> ERROR :NON-SSL command received on SSL-only port. Check your
>   connection settings

**My code**:

```
import socket

ircsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server = "server" 
channel = "#channel" 
ircsock.connect((server, 6697)) 
ircsock.send(bytes("USER "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +" "+ botnick + " " + botnick + "n", "UTF-8"))
ircsock.send(bytes("NICK "+ botnick +"n", "UTF-8")) 
ircsock.send(bytes("JOIN "+ channel +"n", "UTF-8")) 
ircmsg = ircsock.recv(4096).decode("UTF-8")
print(ircmsg)
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the connection socket with an SSL socket.
For example:

```
import ssl
import socket

port = 6697
server = "server"  # Replace me with real address
ctx = ssl.create_default_context(purpose=ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ircsock = ctx.wrap_socket(sock) 
ircsock.connect((server, port))
ircsock.send(bytes("USER "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +" "+ botnick + " " + botnick + "n", "UTF-8"))
...
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with python3.10.7 :/ Any idea ? I get "ssl.SSLError: Cannot create a client socket with a PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER context (_ssl.c:801)"